# Eclipse won't export apk file after updating ADT?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I updated my ADT plugin within Eclipse IDE on April 13th and now it won't export my projects with the apk file extension. Can someone please help me fix this? I can't figure out what's wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what message is showing? and is there any message in problems tab and console?

Comment: Even we can't figure out, with so less information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it.

1. First open CMD as Administrator and set the current directory to your **[JAVA_FOLDER]\bin**
2. Type the following to generate your keystore (You'll be asked for a password). Your parameters go where the bracketed text is.

   `keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore-name.keystore] -alias [key-alias] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
3. In ADT/Eclipse, right click on your project folder, select **Android Tools** >> **Export Unsigned Application Package**
4. Sign your unsigned apk using the generated keystore with this

   `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystore-name].keystore unsigned.apk [key_alias]`
5. Verify you signed it correctly with

   `jarsigner -verify [signed-apk].apk`
6. Your apk is now signed an can be distributed. However, it is recommended to DWORD align the file. So, in CMD, navigate to your **[Android SDK folder]\tools** and type the following

   `zipalign -v 4 [path-to-unaligned].apk [path-to-final].apk`
7. Your apk is finally ready for distribution.

**NOTE**: What I did was let keytool.exe save the keystore in the JAVA bin directory and then moved it to a secure location afterwards.

You can make batch script so you don't type a lot.

For more information:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I was using the recommended Eclipse Mobile referenced on the android dev website but I installed Eclipse Indigo instead with the ADT v21 plugin and it works perfectly now with exporting .apk file extensions. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

So in short: The answer to Eclipse not being able to export .apk files is to use Eclipse Indigo instead.

Which can be found here:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2